# Using Ansible Tower api to get teams associated with a job template

Tags: ansible-tower

The tower api spec has an endpoint[(job_templates/{id}/access_list)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Job_Templates/Job_Templates_job_templates_access_list_list) that list the users that have access to the template.
Is there some way to get the list of teams that have access to this template?